# El-Gamal like encryption, how can i guess the key?

Tags: elgamal-encryption

There is $p$ (large prime number), $g$ (generator of $p$), 
and $x_a$, $x_b$, $r$ (which are between $1$ and $p-1$).

I know $g^{x_a}$, $g^{x_b}$, $g^r$, $g^{x_a\cdot x_b\cdot r} \bmod p$.

How can I get $g^{x_a\cdot r}$?